# Regex in R: Attempting to use qdapRegex package

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract multiple sql queries from a large text file.  The queries all start with the report heading followed by the sql code like this ( **{"app":** ) and end like this ( **"cid":** ).  I am extremely new to regex and do not have a solid grasp on when to use escape characters and so on.  I am using the ex_between() function from the qdapRegex package in R and my code is as follows.

```
sql2 <- ex_between(sql, left = "{/"app/":", right = "/"cid/":", extract = T, 
     include.markers = T)
```

Would someone mind to correct my code or point in the right direction??

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected output for others to test your code

Comment: I can't provide you with that information as what I am trying to extract is proprietary information including email addresses and table and column names from our database.  What I am trying to extract is located between {"app":  and "cid":  .  These are constant throughout the document.

Comment: Well, to start, the escape character is `\`. You should go to https://regex101.com/. It's an online regex tester/debugger which will help you play around with your regex until you can get it to work.

Comment: Thank you.  This is the regex I got from regex101.com                                          
      :\[{"app"(?s)(.*)WC_PROD"} Having been able to figure out the whole expression I am going to use grep instead of ex_between however I am having trouble translating this to R

Comment: Try this regex `{"app":(.*?)"cid":` What you want is in capture group 1.

Comment: yep, thats works perfectly.  Thank you

Comment: To extract a string between two strings, use `stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?s)(?<=\\{\"app\":).*?(?=\"cid\":)")`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpPGCO/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mau use `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package with the following pattern:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "(?s)(?<=\\{\"app\":).*?(?=\"cid\":)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpPGCO/1). `str_extract_all` returns all pattern matches found in each string.

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier enabling `.` to match newline chars
- `(?<=\\{\"app\":)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location in string that is immediately preceded with `{"app":` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\"cid\":)` -  a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires the presence of the `"cid":` text.